# flutter chart how to indicate the value inside the bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the flutter chart library I wanted to display the value inside the bar as in the image I tried several things but it doesn't work

```
          labelAnchor: charts.BarLabelAnchor.middle,
          labelPosition: charts.BarLabelPosition.inside,
          outsideLabelStyleSpec: new charts.TextStyleSpec(
              fontSize: 12, color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.red)),
          insideLabelStyleSpec: new charts.TextStyleSpec(
              fontSize: 12, color: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.red))),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can follow my bar chart configuration. it works on my side

See this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OGF4.png

Comment: Please fix link image name description